# How to open text file in notepad with cmd window in background?

Tags: python-2.7, cmd

I want to open a text file without opening cmd window in the background. I have tried:

```
webbrowser.open('file.txt')
```

but it crashes ArcGIS so I tried following:

```
os.system('file.txt')
```

it opens text file without crashing ArcGIS but cmd window remains in the background and goes away when I close text file.

It is more of a display choice question and just checking if there is any suggestion to avoid cmd window in the background.

Comment: yes. It also shows cmd in background

Answer (score 1):

Save your script with a `.pyw` extension and the console window won't appear.

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts) :

> On Windows systems, there is no notion of an “executable mode”. The Python installer automatically associates .py files with python.exe so that a double-click on a Python file will run it as a script. **The extension can also be .pyw, in that case, the console window that normally appears is suppressed.**

You need to modify the program that calls the "add-in script" to run it with `pythonw.exe` (and not `python.exe` which is the default).

Comment: its part of an add-in so i can't save it with .pyw extension

Comment: script is part of Add-In and should be *.py to create *.esriaddin file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want, but maybe you should create .bat file ([something like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657777/open-text-file-and-program-shortcut-in-windows-batch-file)) and run this with [Python subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).