# Batchfile text files not opening

Tags: batch-file

When I create a .txt in a batch file it asks me to choose a program to read it.
How do I make it reconize it as a .txt and use notepad to open?

For example if i create it like:

```
Echo Hello world >>learn'n.txt
start learn'n.txt
```

The start command would not work because it is classified as a "file" and not a .txt
However:

```
Start learn'n
```

Opens a dialog box asking what program to use to open learn'n with.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there anyway to open it straight with notepad using:

    start learn
And not use start notepad learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `notepad` with the file as a parameter:

```
notepad learn'n.txt
```

You can check what the file type is for the .txt extension using the `assoc` command

```
C:\>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile
```

On my machine .txt files are associated as a txtfile. You can then check what the default program for that file type is using the `ftype` command.

```
c:\>ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

On my machine, files with type txtfile are opened with notepad.exe. Presumably, you need to set this value, to do that, use the following command (obviously putting in the correct path).

```
ftype txtfile=path\to\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Though for you it is probably easier to just use `notepad learn'n.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Mark Ursino on [Open text file and program shortcut in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657777/open-text-file-and-program-shortcut-in-windows-batch-file)

```
Echo Hello world >> learn'n.txt
start notepad "learn'n.txt"
```

I agree with jeremyjjbrown that you shouldn't use apostrophes in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
Echo Hello world >>learn'n.txt
start "" "learn'n.txt"
```

on a normal system where `.txt` files are associated/registered to Notepad (or another editor) then it will open the file.